# 2nd largest eigenvalue and rayleigh quotient

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

2nd largest eigenvalue of a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix is min of max rayleigh quotient over the subspace of dimension 1.

From this definition how do we get that it is equal to the max rayleigh quotient over a $\vec{x}$ such that $\vec{x} \perp \vec{1}$?

Comment: It sounds like you're dealing with a Laplacian (or Laplacian-like) matrix. In general, the eigenspace corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue will not contain $\vec{1}$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer for [2nd smallest eigenvalues and courant-fisher](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/456099/44541) actually answers this as well.

Suppose that $\lambda_1,\geq \cdots,\geq \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

In order for the statement to be correct, you need to assume that $\bar 1$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1$.

Let $(\bar 1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is an orthogonal basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$ using eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ . Then every $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$, $x\perp\bar 1$ can be represented as $\alpha_2x_2+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n$. Substituting in the Rayleigh quotient:
$$
\frac{x^tAx}{x^tx} = \frac{(\alpha_2x_2+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n)^tA(\alpha_2x_2+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n)}{(\alpha_2x_2+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n)^t(\alpha_2x_2+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n)}
= \frac{\lambda_2\alpha_2\|x_2\|^2+\cdots\lambda_n\alpha_n\|x_n\|^2}{\alpha_2\|x_2\|^2+\cdots\alpha_n\|x_n\|^2} \leq \frac{\lambda_2 (\alpha_2\|x_2\|^2+\cdots\alpha_n\|x_n\|^2)}{\alpha_2\|x_2\|^2+\cdots\alpha_n\|x_n\|^2}=\lambda_2
$$

So $\max_{x\perp \bar 1}\frac{x^tAx}{x^tx}\leq\lambda_2$. On the other hand, if $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$ is an eigenvector belonging to the eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ we have $\frac{x^tAx}{x^tx} = \lambda_2$, so actually
$$
\max_{x\perp \bar 1}\frac{x^tAx}{x^tx}=\lambda_2
$$

Comment: i think the answer has a typo.
$\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_n$ in the last two fractions should be
$\alpha_2^2$ and $\alpha_n^2$. In words, the Rayleigh quotient is a weighted average of the eigenvalues, but the weights are $\alpha^2$s which are positive, instead of $\alpha$s, which can be negative.

Comment: @purewater01: I assume you wanted your post to be a comment to Guy's answer. If you meant something else, or if the problem has been fixed, then post again.

Answer (score 2):

You got the [Courant-Fischer minimax principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) wrongly. Denote by $\lambda_2^\downarrow(A)$ the second largest eigenvalue of an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix $A$. The correct statement should be:
$$
\lambda_2^\downarrow(A)
= \min_{\dim(V)=n-1}\ \max_{x\in V,\,x\neq0} \frac{\|x^TAx\|}{\|x\|^2}.\tag{1}
$$
That is, $\lambda_2^\downarrow(A)$ is the minimum of the maximum Rayleigh quotient over all subspaces of **codimension** $1$ (rather than over subspces of **dimension** $1$). If $V$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it has a unit normal vector $y$. So $x\in V$ if and only if $x\perp y$. Therefore $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\lambda_2^\downarrow(A)
= \min_{y\neq0}\ \max_{x\perp y,\,x\neq0} \frac{\|x^TAx\|}{\|x\|^2}.
$$