# 2nd smallest eigenvalues and courant-fisher

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came across the following argument in a lecture about algebraic methods in combinatorics:

> Suppose we have $L$, the laplacian of some graph, and
>   $\mu_1\leq\cdots\leq\mu_n$  are its eigenvalues. Then, for every $x\in R^n$, $x\cdot\bar1=0$,  we have
>   $$
> \frac{x^tLx}{x^tx}\geq\mu_2
> $$

I think that the bound was reasoned by [Courant-Fisher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) and that actually $L$ could be any symmetric real matrix. A similiar bound, only in the other direction and regarding the 2nd largest eigenvalue can be found in this [paper](http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-lecture22.pdf).

Can you explain how exactly was this bound derived from Courant-Fisher?

(I'm aware of the similarity to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430894/2nd-largest-eigenvalue-and-rayleigh-quotient), but this argument might be weaker).

Comment: If I add that $\bar 1$ is an eigenvector of $L$ corresponding to $\mu_1$, will that make it easier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referencing Courant-Fisher was apparently misleading. The explaination is actually pretty basic:

Suppose $(\bar 1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ using eigenvectors corresponding to $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n$ (here comes the assumption that $\bar 1$ is an eigenvector belonging to $\mu_1$). Then every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x\perp\bar 1$ can be represented as $\alpha_2x_2+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n$. Substituting in the Rayleigh quotient:
$$
\frac{x^tLx}{x^tx} = \frac{(\alpha_2x_2+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n)^tL(\alpha_2x_2+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n)}{(\alpha_2x_2+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n)^t(\alpha_2x_2+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n)}
= \frac{\mu_2\alpha_2\|x_2\|^2+\cdots\mu_n\alpha_n\|x_n\|^2}{\alpha_2\|x_2\|^2+\cdots\alpha_n\|x_n\|^2} \geq \frac{\mu_2 (\alpha_2\|x_2\|^2+\cdots\alpha_n\|x_n\|^2)}{\alpha_2\|x_2\|^2+\cdots\alpha_n\|x_n\|^2}=\mu_2
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the $\alpha_i$ be squared too?