# Second-smallest eigenvalue as $\min_x \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In [Mining Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/book.pdf#page=383), page 365, the following theorem is stated without proof:

> Let A be a symmetric matrix. then the second-smallest eigenvalue of A is equal to 
>   $\displaystyle \min_{x} {x^TAx}$, when the minimum is taken over all unit vectors x that are orthogonal to the eigenvector $v_1$ associated with the smallest eigenvalue.

This phrasing seems somewhat sloppy, because let's look at the case where the smallest eigenvalue has an eigenspace of dimension $>1$. I think we will not really get the second-smallest eigenvalue $\lambda _2$ but the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda _1$ itself, because we can take another unit eigenvector of $\lambda _1$ that is orthogonal to $v_1$, and it will satisfy the minimization problem. ($x^TAx=x^T \lambda x =\lambda$)

So probably the right two theorems are:

> 1. The $k^{th}$ smallest (*distinct*) eigenvalue of L is equal to 
>      $\displaystyle \min_{x} {x^TAx}$, when the minimum is taken over all unit vectors x that are orthogonal to all of the eigenvectors associated with the smallest $k-1$ eigenvalues.
> 2. The second smallest eigenvalue of L *counted with multiplicities according to the dimensions of the eigenspaces* is equal to 
>      $\displaystyle \min_{x} {x^TAx}$, when the minimum is taken over all unit vectors x that are orthogonal to an eigenvector associated with the smallest eigenvalue.

For the $k^{th}$ smallest in the second proposition, we ask for orthogonality to all eigenvectors of the smaller eigenvalues.

Is it right? And how do I prove in both cases that $\displaystyle \min_{x} {x^TAx} \leq \lambda _k$?

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433169/minimize-xtax-subject-to-x-1-show-that-xtax-is-the-smallest) shows that without the second constraint we get the smallest eigenvalue, because the $x$ that gives the minimum is an eigenvector of $\frac{A+A^T}{2}=A$, and hence gives as the value of the quadratic form its associated eigenvalue. The answer there also seems to hint at the necessity of an assumption on the positive semi-definiteness of $A$; is it needed? The book does not require it.

Comment: It seems that the smallest eigenvalue of Laplacian is always zero and always simple. I've found that this fact is mentioned for example here, http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/eigenvals-x.pdf , at page 7. And since this eigenspace is one-dimensional, their method for finding second smallest eigenvalue seems to work.

Comment: what is the relationship between $L$ and $A$?

Comment: They're the same :) The fact that the laplacian has smallest eigenvalue 0 is simply because it is semidefinite (symmetric and diagonally semi-dominant) and 1,...,1 is an eigenvector of 0. That it is simple is interesting, but the theorem in the book relates to all symmetric matrices, not only laplacians.

Comment: See the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).  We are using the fact that $L$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Leullame As far as I read this part of the book that you've provided  (only page 365), they state this only about Laplacians :)

Comment: @Evgeny The link says that the multiplicity of 0 in the laplacian is not always zero, but equal to the number of connected components of the graph. (And I don't completely understand the reason.)

Comment: @Leullame Sorry, my bad, I was inaccurate. About multiiplicity of zero eigenvalue. If graph has multiple connected components, you can rearrange vertices such way that Laplacian will become block-diagonal. And instead of one eigenvector $\mathbb{1}$ you can construct multiple eigenvectors that have ones at entries which correspond to particular connected component and zeros at other entries.

Comment: I'd chalk this up to a difference in semantics/convention. In some contexts, particularly with symmetric matrices, one enumerates the eigenvalues without regard for multiplicity; that is, $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\dots\geq\lambda_n$. In that case the statement holds without qualification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name  "min-max theorem" given in the comments lead to the following [very elegant proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/456099/116490).

To repeat in our context: given  a symmetric matrix A, we construct an orthonormal basis $\{ v_1,b_2,...,b_n \}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ using the eigenvectors of A (which is possible due to the symmetry of A), using the eigenvector $v_1$ from the theorem. 
As we only look at the space orthogonal to $v_1$ in the minimization, $\{ b_2,...,b_n \}$ is an orthonormal basis.

We note that the dot product can be done coordinate-wise in any orthonormal basis, and hence for all unit vectors $x=(x_2,...,x_n)$ in this orthogonal space: $${x^TAx}=(\sum_{j=2}^n x_j b_j^T)A(\sum_{i=2}^n x_ib_i)=\sum _{i,j}x_i x_j b_j^T A b_i=\sum _{i,j}x_i x_j b_j^T \lambda _i b_i$$
As $Ab_i=\lambda_i b_i$. Now we use $b_j^T b_j=\delta_{ij}$, as they compose an orthonormal basis, to get:
$$=\sum _{i}\lambda_i x_i^2 \geq \sum _{i}\lambda_2 x_i^2=\lambda_2$$

Since $x$ is of unit length. we proved that for all $x$ on which we minimize, ${x^TAx} \geq \lambda_2$, and hence $\min{x^TAx} \geq \lambda_2$. The other direction is easy and in written in the question itself. $\square$

The proof assumed indeed that we count the eigenvalues according to their algebraic multiplicity, $\lambda_1 \leq ... \leq \lambda _n$.